# Connectionstring is not being passed from dbconnection to dbfactory?

Tags: c#, sql, database, factory

I am currently using `dbfactory? for accessing my database, but for some reason is the connection string empty when it is being initialized from a`dbconnection`?

How come?

Code:

```
        var connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"];
        DbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connect.ConnectionString);
        Console.WriteLine("DbConnection: " + db.ConnectionString);
        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(db);
        System.Data.Common.DbConnection cn = factory.CreateConnection();
        Console.WriteLine("DbConnection from factory: " + cn.ConnectionString);
        Repository = new Repository();
        return Repository.Load(() => cn);
```

output:

```
DbConnection: Server=<connetionstring>
DbConnection from factory:
```

Comment: Can you put that in `try` block and try to open the connection

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
//get the information out of the configuration file.
var connectionStringSettings = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"];

//get the proper factory and mandatory to have SQL Provide name in the connection string
DbProviderFactory factory = 
  DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringSettings.ProviderName);

//create a command of the proper type.
DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
//set the connection string
conn.ConnectionString = connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString;

//open the connection
conn.Open();

Repository = new Repository();
return Repository.Load(() => conn);
```